# Upstart job won't start

Tags: upstart

I have a simple upstart job: - `/etc/init/hmastart.conf`

I want to test it, so i run:-

`service hmastart start`

But i receive the following error:-

`start: Unknown job: hmastart`

I get the same error message if i try:

`start hmastart`

I have also tried adding sudo to the beginning, but i get the same error.

Here is my script

```
description "Starts HMA VPN"
author "Me <myself@i.com>"

start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

expect fork

exec sudo /usr/local/bin/hma-vpn -p tcp London
```

My conf file has the same permissions as all the other conf files in /etc/init.

Could someone please tell me why this script cannot be found/run?

Many thanks in advance!!`

Comment: I just put your script in `/etc/init/hmstart.conf` on my system, changed the command in exec to something harmless, and ran it with `sudo service hmastart start`. It started right up. I'd double-check all the permissions and locations. Also please indicate your Ubuntu version (I tested on 13.04).

Comment: Thanks roadmr, you kind of helped me answer this. My script actually contained lots of comments, like the ones in [this example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Writing_Services). By removing them, like i did when i posted my script here, it ran like a charm. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should look like:

```
# description "Starts HMA VPN"
# author "Me <myself@i.com>"

start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

expect fork

exec sudo /usr/local/bin/hma-vpn -p tcp London
```

To start it, use:

```
sudo service hmastart start
```

Comment: Thanks Radu, but description and author are valid without being commented out

Comment: Well, for me it works like I said

Answer (score 0):

If your user doesn't have the NOPASSWD option configured for sudo then that could be why it's not starting as expected.  To configure your account for sudo access without a password, edit the sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Append to the file:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Where username is your username in your system.  Save and close the file.

WARNING: this decreases security by allowing your account to run any command as root without requiring a password!